# How to reuse conditional check for each function?

Tags: javascript, function

I have many functions example like this

```
function update() {
  if (isAdminUser()) {
    return false;
  }
  ...
}
function get() {
  if (isAdminUser()) {
    return false;
  }
  ...
}
...
```

is there any possible way to have the conditional statement

```
 if (isAdminUser()) {
   return false;
 })
```

written once and run by itself at the beginning of each function. I'm using javascript

Comment: You could shrink the whole block to `return !isAdminUser();`. Also a higher order function could be feasible

Comment: What about `let result = isAdminUser() && get()`?

Comment: Thanks for comment. I think higher order function can help me in this case, because I don't want to have to rewrite the condition statement for each function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a higher order function to encapsulate the logic needed to run before a specific function is run. Higher order functions take functions as parameters, therefore a possible solution to your problem could look like this:

```js
function withIsAdminUser(callback) {
  return function() { 
    if (isAdminUser()) {
      return false;
    }
    return callback();
  }
}

function getRaw() {
  // Do something here, this whole function could also be inlined
}
const get = withIsAdminUser(getRaw);
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, it can help me in this case. But in case there are many common condition statement it will look like withIsAdminUser(withIsNativePlaform(withIsActive((getRaw)));.Do you have any solution for the above situation?

Comment: the function chain can get quite messy, if those checks are the same for all of the functions, you might want to put it in one higher order function (and choose a fitting name)

Comment: if you collect them all and put them in one higher order function, it will becomes less flexible have to accept this or is there a better way

Answer (score 0):

If you use TypeScript try decorators.

Docs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/decorators.html#decorators

Comment: Thanks for answer, but apply typescript it breaks my code now

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can define a function that can accept another function as an argument and returns false if that function (i.e isAdminUser in your code snippet) returns true

```
const checkUser = func => func() && false
```

then the function can be used like:

```
function update() {
    if (checkUser(isAdminUser)) {
        // update() logic will only run if user is not admin
    }

}
function get() {
   if (checkUser(isAdminUser)) {
      // get() logic will only run if user is not admin   
   }
 }
```

Comment: I don't know how checkUser function can help in this case